# wordpress advanced custom fields order posts by date-picker

Tags: wordpress

For those familiar with the ACF plugin...

I have some events posts that are currently displaying in post order (see code below). I would like them to display in the order specified by the date-picker.

Can anyone tell me what to amend in the following - I have tried the documentation on the site, but my PHP is basic.

It says I need to add

```
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
```

But no joy.

```
<?php function le_whatson_aside() {

//THis loop is for the CPT
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'events', // enter your custom post type
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=> '10',  // overrides posts per page in theme settings
        'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'audience', //name of custom taxonomy
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'everyone' //name of category
        )
    )

    );

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $loop->have_posts() ):
    ?>

    <div>
        <h2>What's On</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="whatson entry-content"> 
        <?php   
        while( $loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); global $post;
            ?>
            <p class="whatson-date"><?php echo date("dS F Y",strtotime(get_field('date')));?></p>
            <a  href="<?php echo get_permalink() ?>"><h4 class="whatson-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h4></a>

            <?php
        endwhile;
        ?>
    </div>

<?php
endif; }
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
orderby=date or `post_date`
```

If not the easiest way is to save your custom field 'startdate' as a unix timestamp. To do this, add the following to your theme's functions.php

```
// CREATE UNIX TIME STAMP FROM DATE PICKER
function custom_unixtimesamp ( $post_id ) {
if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'events' ) {
$startdate = get_post_meta($post_id, 'startdate', true);

    if($startdate) {
        $dateparts = explode('/', $startdate);
        $newdate1 = strtotime(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateparts[1].'/'.$dateparts[0].'/'.$dateparts[2])));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'unixstartdate', $newdate1  );
    }
}
 }
     add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_unixtimesamp', 100, 2);
```

The do:

```
$today = time();

$args = array(
'post_type' => 'events',
'posts_per_page' => 5,

'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'unixstartdate',
        'compare' => '>=',
        'value' => $today,
    )
),

'meta_key' => 'startdate',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$events = $query->posts;
```

[Got it from here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-advanced-custom-fields-sorting-by-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours looking for this and I can confirm it works. See my code below.

If you're trying for a loop on a page with other loops, with a bunch of template parts in there, and you would also like to sort by a category, it goes :

```
    $today = time();

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'events',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'start',
            'value' => $today,
            'compare' => '>=',
        )
    ),

    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
        'taxonomy' => 'the_taxonomy',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'the-name'
        )
    ),
    'meta_key' => 'start',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    ) );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    $the_query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content-events' );
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Of course, you have to include Unix the function beforehand.

```
function custom_unixtimesamp ( $post_id ) {
if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) == 'events' ) {
$startdate = get_post_meta($post_id, 'start', true);
    if($startdate) {
        $dateparts = explode('_', $startdate);
        $newdate1 = strtotime(date('d.m.Y H:i:s', strtotime($dateparts[1].'/'.$dateparts[0].'/'.$dateparts[2])));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'unixstartdate', $newdate1  );
    }
}
 }
add_action( 'save_post', 'custom_unixtimesamp', 100, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it like this. Create a "named" meta query and then order by that query. The meta query uses "EXITS" to filter out posts that don't have a date set. This works with the ACF date picker when the dates are saved to the database using the default format `d/m/Y`. This approach also works with the datetime picker.

```php
$query = new WP_Query([
    "meta_query" => [
        "custom_date" => [
            "key"     => "date",
            "compare" => "EXISTS",
            "type"    => "DATETIME",
        ]
    ],
    "orderby" => [
        "custom_date" => "ASC",
    ],
]);
```

Be sure to update the value for `key` to whatever your ACF field name is.